# How to use Javascipt Replace characters in Blogger

Tags: javascript, replace, blogger

I want to replace some characters: [ngu1], [ngu2] to [chanquadi] and I use my

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var heo1 = document.querySelector(<.post-body>);
    var heo2 = heo1.replace("[ngu1]", "chanquadi");
    document.write(+ heo2 +);
</script>
```

But it doesn't works, please help me to solve it.
Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `querySelector` appears to be invalid, please take a look at the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Also you cannot replace directly from the `Element` returned by the `querySelector` function.
An approach is to get the `innerText` of the Element and then do the replace.

Finally I do not understand what are you trying to do with the `document.write` sentence, as it appears to be invalid too.

Try if this works for your problem:

```js
var heo1 = document.querySelector('.post-body');
heo1.innerText = heo1.innerText.replace(/ngu1|ngu2/gi, "chanquadi");
```

```html
<div class="post-body">
[ngu1] [ngu2] -- chanquadi
</div>
```